# TensorFlow Raspberry Pi Examples

Tags: python, makefile, tensorflow, raspberry-pi2

I'm really not familiar with make. So I don't understand the meaning of those steps in 2 tutorials ("TensorFlow Makefile" and "TensorFlow Raspberry Pi Examples") to make my project on laptop work on raspberry pi 2

TensorFlow Makefile:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile

TensorFlow Raspberry Pi Examples:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples

As far as i know,"TensorFlow Makefile" will convert the tensorflow source,lib to executable file. "TensorFlow Raspberry Pi Examples" means convert your project to executable file then run the file in `your_project/gen/bin/your_project`

```
tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples/label_image/gen/bin/label_image
```

Hence,if I have a project on my laptop and want to load my project into Pi 2 ("TensorFlow Makefile" is already done). I just copy it to my pi 2 and do :

```
make -f tensorflow/my_project/Makefile
```

then run :

```
tensorflow/my_project/gen/bin/my_project
```

This is how to make your project work on raspberry pi 2, right ?

Comment: "I don't understand the meaning of those steps in 2 tutorials".  It might be helpful to share the links to those two tutorials.

Comment: they are "TensorFlow Makefile" and "TensorFlow Raspberry Pi Examples"

Comment: Those aren't links.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to [brush up on how Makefiles work](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/), for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work for Makefiles which have the option to cross-compile from a (presumably) x86(_64?)-architecture laptop to an ARM-architecture Raspberry Pi.

You're in luck, though: Google's included options in TensorFlow's `Makefile` to cross-compile between architectures!

If you look at [line 123 of the Makefile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile#L123-L126), you'll see a comment about this.

> Default to running on the same system we're compiling on.
>   You should override `TARGET` on the command line if you're cross-compiling, e.g.
>   `make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile TARGET=ANDROID`

So, simply make the project like so:

```
$ make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile TARGET=PI
```

This will compile TensorFlow for the RPi.

Incidentally, if you can, it may be easier to simply compile TensorFlow *on* the RPi by either pulling the sources from git or transferring it onto the RPi via USB, and building there.